# In chartjs, add link text on tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to add link (href) to label text in tooltip.

So I tried customized as below.

```
callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var val = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return 'test ' + '(<a href="foo">filter</a>)' + label;
        }
      }
```

demo here : https://codepen.io/ezrinn/pen/OJJbqwo

But the result is not work well. href is shown as text. How to add clickable tooltip as link ? Please help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you are unable to add HTML content into the tooltips. Try creating an external tooltip instead.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/html.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using escape sequence

```
return 'test' + \'(<a href="foo">filter</a>)' + label;
```